# JSP::Confused with the session objects

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I just started exploring Java Servlets and JSP and am a little confused about the sessions object. Inside a servlet I have this:

```
public class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("_session", "_value");
                response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp");         
        }
}
```

Now, inside page2.jsp, there is a session object as well, but when I do this

```
<%
out.print(session.getAttribute("_session"))
%>
```

it does not seem to get the value (as if it is not set). I tried setting a boolean attribute to true but in the jsp page it returns a false. Can someone tell me the right way of doing this? As to what I am trying to do, I want to share some session variables.

Comment: Are you sure that your browser is configured to support cookies? The redirection goes back to the client, and then back to the server. Maybe the cookie is lost.

Comment: You need to enable cookies - are you sure you are doing it?

Comment: @Eyal and @OpenSource: Yes. My browser supports cookies. I am trying out a few suggestions given below. Will get back.

Comment: In future questions, you should mention up-front that you're using GAE, it makes things different enough to make a difference in many cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use request.getRequestDispatcher().forward() instead of response.sendRedirect();

So your code would be:

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
 session.setAttribute("_session", "_value");
 request.getRequestDispatcher("page2.jsp").forward();
```

Basically, response.sendRedirect() does not preserve session info, so it's not there when the jsp gets it.  request.forward() does preserve the session.

See http://www.coderanch.com/t/170618/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/sendRedirect-Vs-requestdispatcher-forward

Comment: The last line is syntactically invalid and he's setting a session attribute, so it should be there in the redirected request.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks... It works now... I had to change that `forward` to `forward(request, response)` though.

Comment: @Legend: That might be container dependent. Your initial approach works fine on both Tomcat 6 and Glassfish 3 here. I tested it. That would be a bug in container used by Google Appengine.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for the clarification. I will raise a bug report with Google as I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your container supports it, use [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)!

Java side:

```
HttpSession session  = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("foo", "bar");
```

JSP side:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        ...
        <p>${foo}</p>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

And that will give you a paragraph containing the string `bar`.

Comment: +1 for EL. Just beginning to hear some Java side technologies :)

Comment: @skaffman - is the original problem (redirect not preserving session info) GAE-specific? I actually use session attributes (vs request attributes) when I want to preserve information across a redirect, using JBoss+Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Although not the best approach (I'd rather use EL `${_session}` than a *scriptlet*), this should work fine. Your problem lies somewhere else. Are you running the code you think you're running? How are you compiling and deploying the code? Didn't you trim too much off from the given example? The session is namely domain and context dependent, if you redirect to a different domain and/or context, then a new session would be created. Also, the session is backed by a cookie, does the browser have cookies enabled? Else you'll have to use [`HttpServletResponse#encodeRedirectURL()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL%28java.lang.String%29) to append the session identifier to the redirect URL.

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("page2.jsp"));
```

---

**Update**: to debug if it's really the *same* session, do in the servlet:

```
System.out.println("Session ID: " + session.getId());
```

and in the JSP:

```
<p>Session ID: ${pageContext.session.id}</p>
```

Also installing a HTTP header tracker like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)'s [*Net*](http://getfirebug.com/network) panel may bring new insights. The HTTP response should include a `Set-Cookie` header with the session ID and the subsequent HTTP requests should include a `Cookie` header with the same cookie name/value, usually `JSESSIONID` with a long hex value like as on [this screenshot](http://tweakers.net/ext/f/FyyWop3fRWFENHLFqf969xTg/full.png).

---

**Update 2:** since I was suprised because a forward apparently fixes this issue, I tried to reproduce this on Tomcat 6 and Glassfish 3, but this approach works perfectly on the both servers. So I suspect a bug in the container used by Appengine, that it is not setting the cookie correctly during the redirect.

As evidence, here's a screen which proves that Glassfish is setting the cookie by `Set-Cookie` **and** firing the redirect by `Location`:

[image]

Comment: I am using Google App Engine framework. Writing a few servlets and jsp files inside the project that Eclipse created.